# Script to Install software with powershell

Tags: powershell, installation, uninstallation

I wrote a script to un-install a specific program, which works great. But now I want to make that after I remove it, the program would re-install again. This is my un-install code.

```
$Workstation = read-host "Enter Workstation ID"

$app =  Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $Workstation | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "PMSC" }

$app.Uninstall()
```

Could you guys point me in the right path to start an install script? I did some research and I found stuff like start-process but I was not sure how to implement it. I am new with PowerShell, so any help would be much appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Have you had a look at the `Install` and `Reinstall` methods of the `Win32_Product` class?

Comment: I have not, I will look into this. Thanks!